# Cutting circle into polygon in OpenLayers?

Tags: polygon, openlayers, circle

I have a square polygon and I want to cut circles into it where I click with the mouse. The result should be a new polygon with holes in it.

This is my attempt so far but I can't get it to work.
The idea is to create a "fog of war" effect where the map gets revealed at the position of the user.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Fog of War using OpenLayers

```
<script>
    const REVEAL_RADIUS = 50; 
    const COORDS = ol.proj.fromLonLat([13, 52]);

    const map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: COORDS,
            zoom: 14
        })
    });

    const fogSource = new ol.source.Vector();

    const fogLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: fogSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
            })
        })
    });

    map.addLayer(fogLayer);

    const worldExtent = [-180, -90, 180, 90];
    const fogFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(ol.proj.transformExtent(worldExtent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
    });
    fogSource.addFeature(fogFeature);

    map.on('click', function(e) {
        const resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
        const adjustedRadius = REVEAL_RADIUS * resolution;

        const circleGeom = new ol.geom.Circle(e.coordinate, adjustedRadius);
        const polygonGeom = ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(circleGeom);

        const jstsParser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();
        jstsParser.inject(ol.geom.Point, ol.geom.LineString, ol.geom.LinearRing, ol.geom.Polygon, ol.geom.MultiPolygon);

        const fogJsts = jstsParser.read(fogFeature.getGeometry());
        const circleJsts = jstsParser.read(polygonGeom);

        const subtractedJsts = fogJsts.difference(circleJsts);
        const subtractedGeom = jstsParser.write(subtractedJsts);

        fogFeature.setGeometry(subtractedGeom);
        fogSource.refresh();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
    const resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    const adjustedRadius = REVEAL_RADIUS * resolution;
    const circleGeom = new ol.geom.Circle(e.coordinate, adjustedRadius);
    const polygonGeom = ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(circleGeom);
    fogFeature.getGeometry().appendLinearRing(polygonGeom.getLinearRing(0));
});
```

will add a circular hole to the polygon - it will not check if the hole overlaps an existing hole.

**UPDATE**

You could handle overlapping holes using `turf.intersect` https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect

```
const initalFeature = fogFeature.clone();

map.on('click', function(e) {
    const resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    const adjustedRadius = REVEAL_RADIUS * resolution;
    const circleGeom = new ol.geom.Circle(e.coordinate, adjustedRadius);
    const polygonGeom = ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(circleGeom);
    const tempFeature = initalFeature.clone();
    tempFeature.getGeometry().appendLinearRing(polygonGeom.getLinearRing(0));
    const turfFeature1 = new ol.format.GeoJSON().writeFeatureObject(fogFeature, {rightHanded: true});
    const turfFeature2 = new ol.format.GeoJSON().writeFeatureObject(tempFeature, {rightHanded: true});
    const subtractedGeom = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeature(turf.intersect(turfFeature1, turfFeature2)).getGeometry();
    fogFeature.setGeometry(subtractedGeom);
});
```

Working example https://jsbin.com/kusumopage/edit?html,output

Note that if you have a filled area surrounded by holes the geometry will be a MultiPolygon

[image]